# Local Binders : keeps on increasing when I switch between fragments

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, android-binder

Number of Local Binders: keep on increasing when I am switching between fragments with replace() method. I have fixed all of the memory leaks but not getting any memory leak for this.
I am running dumpsys meminfo package package.name command to see the memory usages.

Why my local binder number is increasing? It's not decreasing even when activity is destroyed and created again.

```
App Summary
                       Pss(KB)
                        ------
           Java Heap:     4880
         Native Heap:    15540
                Code:      640
               Stack:       40
            Graphics:        0
       Private Other:     2604
              System:    18579
 
               TOTAL:    42283      TOTAL SWAP (KB):        0
 
 Objects
               Views:       33         ViewRootImpl:        1
         AppContexts:        8           Activities:        1
              Assets:        4        AssetManagers:        0
       Local Binders:      207        Proxy Binders:       50
       Parcel memory:       11         Parcel count:       45
    Death Recipients:       60      OpenSSL Sockets:        0
            WebViews:        0
```